# How do I remove the legend, labels and all the numbers from the graphs from apex charts

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[image]

I've tried everything I can. If anyone can help me out, it'll be great. I want the numbers on the graphs and the legend gone

Comment: how did you add border radius to the bar chart on top and bottom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Legend and data-labels can be disabled by

```js
const options = {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to remove all the additional graphics, try using sparkline which will only keep the chart and hide everything.

```js
sparkline: {
  enabled: true
}
```

Comment: What about the numbers on the axes? How do I eliminate them?

Comment: Also, can I eliminate the weird +,-,search bar at the top

Comment: chart: {...
      sparkline: {
        enabled: true
      },
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
       },
    },
dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        show: false,
    },

 yaxis: {
        show: false,        
    }, 
    xaxis: {
      show: false,
      labels: {
          show: false,
      },   
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,        
      },   
      tooltip: {
          enabled: false,
      }
    }, 

https://github.com/moesaid/cleopatra/blob/406db65cf154df433fe4199e7fc36cd9a8f1a03d/src/js/charts/analytics_1.js

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
}
```